# ¿Cómo leer propiedad de un JSON con Win Forms?

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente JSON:

```
{
  "resp": {
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiJiMDE5YTNmYy0xM2RhLTQ0MjYtOWQzOC02NmYxMzAyMTA5M2IiLCJleHAiOjE1MzYxMjE3OTIsIm5iZiI6MCwiaWF0IjoxNTM2MTIxNDkyLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2lkcC5jb21wcm9iYW50ZXNlbGVjdHJvbmljb3MuZ28uY3IvYXV0aC9yZWFsbXMvcnV0LXN0YWciLCJhdWQiOiJhcGktc3RhZyIsInN1YiI6Ijk2YTFmOThhLTA2YjMtNGY5Ni1iODc4LWQ2MzNkY2I2MTdmOCIsInR5cCI6IkJlYXJlciIsImF6cCI6ImFwaS1zdGFnIiwic2Vzc2lvbl9zdGF0ZSI6IjA5ZjBlZDFmLTU2N2ItNGRhMy1iZTJjLTM1OGIwYmFhMWU1YyIsImNsaWVudF9zZXNzaW9uIjoiMGRhMTRhZWEtNWRjYS00MTRmLTk1NmYtMzFlOTU2ZWRmYzZhIiwiYWxsb3dlZC1vcmlnaW5zIjpbXSwicmVzb3VyY2VfYWNjZXNzIjp7ImFjY291bnQiOnsicm9sZXMiOlsibWFuYWdlLWFjY291bnQiLCJ2aWV3LXByb2ZpbGUiXX19LCJuYW1lIjoiUklDSEFSRCBFRFVBUkRPIFZJUVVFWiBQRVJFWiIsInByZWZlcnJlZF91c2VybmFtZSI6ImNwZi0wMS0xMjcyLTA1MDdAc3RhZy5jb21wcm9iYW50ZXNlbGVjdHJvbmljb3MuZ28uY3IiLCJnaXZlbl9uYW1lIjoiUklDSEFSRCBFRFVBUkRPIiwicG9sIjoiNWI4MGI0NDc5ZWNlMzYwMzJiMDdkMmViIiwiZmFtaWx5X25hbWUiOiJWSVFVRVogUEVSRVoiLCJwb2xpY3ktaWQiOiI1OGE2MjAzMzc2ZWFlMTQwOGNlNWU3ZGQiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImNwZi0wMS0xMjcyLTA1MDdAc3RhZy5jb21wcm9iYW50ZXNlbGVjdHJvbmljb3MuZ28uY3IifQ.b5ktALbgyOhM1-PBMtVyRMEaRn0yEsUZBRkHtwf5VuTHKEJTCzuU-ADvBoAz_jPs-MPBeUYWWRgcAxfez6cRDDXEp8WDoNy62S7V2mcBkaLjkR7IzTy5jcPKDg_qG7k7pVGIqc2cqmbk2fwkogdP1WiAxdbzGsTMNflj053fuf5Hjnob7oloRJrjBuHKc1wJbeMMGY8Eo_eAb4Halqo3yAWpy6lcoeBujIaw9M1sXPXQPnoePncD8dooU55ugxnrkILFIPHD3QkNKBQi5eiC-Hy_Bc0kaN8CttjGRMohXTeveI0GkxTy819-3HnXALWBeH218AGtx_Zmztn7RjVuPA",
    "expires_in": 300,
    "refresh_expires_in": 36000,
    "refresh_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.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.UQTx-HTP2I5w3Bbi8rlWNydnirQghhM90tsui2_9TFnjw8QPLjRYvvf_Q2pwfojO1piUkFItEhFnUg9VbWyOpBW1RhkuDwxnTLGRWz4MReWkuYCtlIXPn-4EdB2BkryC9KNADTbQGGSQYlgrSS0yRlShAbne9-pCh3WlhjFQ42aq0DdhLXB_3H2GVv5dmYcu_axRW4I6uMBRqtpt-MqtuwYLSKaIGN6D2xhA1K_7SP_BWj0uN6l9u1S1jhAXwH6WLf86NqwGXiOwdXnf4n8qEKZRmNwM8V0id1MK6bkg5caCHFZ8bESifq6dXZFaIyt7wfkUGpWmTYqCNp_MdhXE3Q",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "id_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.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.XKs5kL_KHRqBRP3oGMVruXmv70aHKUZ4_zMfoQHnsQAKnRtrbYd-jkVXvSTtXv_Cd-KvjBALMenyfzumq848r70mCUB7im6BDdb40XHWgIuFKo7lZtne_xa20i8CocVVk6LlxiHhr8gUXtdkiYEAN_PIt3YnTrRuEjxLxNhOHgaO9_-TL_mXxUP4bHaWqzU4zWLTQ0zBN39Aww9JCXTF8GvPPBtJPZtFQvg_XXDQbEmbzMh8LsHNSYEefTcu1-wqjQaUDicJNNNSd69ERxZPys4ycOVDlM6ik4gDB0ZXLnwbV1utTz6shN76Fitil5yEwQq7XeDvJsSmcjKtr1H2Yw",
    "not-before-policy": 0,
    "session_state": "09f0ed1f-567b-4da3-be2c-358b0baa1e5c"
  }
}
```

¿Cómo obtengo solo el `acces_token` de ese JSON con c# winforms?

Comment: Hola mengano, bienvenido al sitio. Deberías explicar mejor tu problema. Decir que has intentado, decir si te falla y donde, si no entiendes algo... Lee [ask] y [tour] y edita tu pregunta para ampliarla y adecuarla al sitio. Además tendrás tu primera medalla!!!

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza [`Newtonsoft.JsonConvert`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) para convertir el json a un objeto y luego acceder las propiedades del mismo:

```
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);

string token = json.resp.access_token;
MessageBox.Show(token);
```

Recuerda agregar la libreria por medio a [nuget](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-console) con el siguiente comando:

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Comment: ya intente eso y la variable json me queda null siempre. No lo deserealiza con el jsonconvert